# What rooms to unlock to reach the backside of the Yavin IV stronghold?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm interested in buying the stronghold but not the whole lot.
As i am a preferred at the moment, i'd like to know how much cash i need to save up to unlock the area's that i want.

The part that i am most interested in is the main room, the bridge and the area behind it.

From Dulfy.net

```
Room #  Room Name          Credits      Cartel Coins    
0       Initial Purchase   2.5 mil      2500 CC     
1       Temple Room 1      825k         700 CC  
2       Temple Room 2      975k         800 CC  
3       Upper Stairwell    450k         400 CC  
4       Lower Stairwell    450k         400 CC 
5       Temple Basement    1.5 mil      1200 CC
6       Temple Balcony     1.2 mil      1000 CC
7       Temple Grounds     2.6 mil      2000 CC
8       Sanctuary 1        1.25 mil     1000 CC
9       Sanctuary 2        1.25 mil     1000 CC
Total                      13 mil       11000 CC
```

I suspect that i need:

- Initial unlock 2.5 mil
- Upper Stairwell 450k
- Temple Balcony 1.2 mil

Not sure what the Temple grounds are or if i need them.
Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [video](http://tor-decorating.com/yavin-4-temple/) shows the entire stronghold as it is being unlocked.

From this video it shows that the following rooms are needed to reach the open jungle area in the back of the stronghold.

```
Initial unlock    2.5 mil
Upper Stairwell   450k
Temple Balcony    1.2 mil
Temple grounds    2.6 mil

Total             6 750 000 credits (6.75 mil) or 5900 CC
```